# AdonisJs Cannot find module 'phc-bcrypt'

Tags: adonis.js

When I call some route I receive this error:  Cannot find module 'phc-bcrypt'

Cannot find module 'phc-bcrypt'

I am working with AdonisJS 5

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you just need to install the package, like:

```sh
npm install --save phc-bcrypt
```